# Having trouble with applying filters to images in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, image-processing, kotlin

I am trying to apply filters on an image in Android Studio. Having trouble with Android's EffectFactory. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's one library that I know of - [Kfilter](https://github.com/isaac-udy/Kfilter).

It's a small Android library for adding image effects/filters to photos and videos, written in Kotlin. It provides a simple interface to create photo and video filters as you would find in applications such as Snapchat or Instagram. Check out other new libraries [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-image-processing-libraries-c4ba9b92281), see if any of them serves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can find additional examples of Kfilter being used?(aside from the provided example)